# Does briefly flying in air hurt my car?

Tags: suspension, infiniti

I drive a big SUV (infiniti qx80). I was going down a steep hill at slightly above the speed limit (around 45mph), and the road had a bump like this: [image]

My car flew briefly in air and then landed. I didn't hear any strange noise other than the landing noise, but it was pretty scary. I wasn't familiar with the area, so I didn't expect there would be this huge bump in the road.

Will this damage my car?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, **Yes**. Maybe it didn't hurt it where you can tell this time, but remember, **cars were meant to stay on the ground, not do Dukes of Hazzard stunt flying**. Every time something like this happens, you are putting undue stress on your springs, tires, rims, and suspension. Every time this happens, there has been a little more life which has left the vehicle sooner than it would have if it had never happened. If the vehicle lands wrong it could cause frame or unibody damage depending on the vehicle. Most important of all, it can cause damage to you the driver and to your passengers if you hit hard enough.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this damage my car?

Hopefully it hasn't. In principle, sure, dropping a car from a sufficient height will break it. And injure people who may be in it.

Next time, pay attention to the posted speed limits and road signage, especially when driving on roads you don't know well. If you weren't too far above the speed limit when this happened, you should probably contact the county and inform them of this incident, so they can flatten the bump or lower the speed limit.

Answer (score 1):

as of my experience if your steering haven't changed and no knocking in the suspension you should be ok however you should just take a look at the suspension in case the bump did hit some thing and bent it just keep in mind cars a build to last not break from rough driving especially suvs.